# Which of the following instructions can run in unprivileged mode? 1) Load 2)Store 3) Input 4)Output

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, user-mode-linux

Trying to understand user mode vs kernel mode and which instruction can run in unprivileged mode.

Per Abraham-Siberschatz, all of these may require SysCall.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which CPU it is and how the OS configured it.

For example; for 80x86 the `in` and `out` instructions can be executed in user mode if:

- the IOPL field (IO privilege level) is set to be not less than the current privilege level.
- the IO Permission Bitmap (in the current Task State Segment) is configured to allow access to the specific IO port/s.

Of course a lot of IO is memory mapped, and that also allows a kernel to map any "memory mapped IO" areas into user space.

In general; a monolithic kernel will run device drivers in kernel space and won't allow user mode code to access any kind of IO directly; and a micro-kernel will run device drivers in user space and will explicitly configure things so that a device driver process can do input/output for the device it is driving (but not any other device).

Comment: So, 'LOAD' , 'STORE' can run in Kernel mode only. However, In, Out can be processor specific.

Comment: @rakeshsaraf: Loads and stores are all kinds of memory accesses - no software can make sense without them. Of course what you can access (load data from or store data to) depends on what the kernel let you access; and this includes loads and stores to memory mapped IO.

Comment: @Brenden:Thanks.